# Joining with Subquerys, antipattern?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table A and a table B which I want to join, I only need a few columns so I thought it would be good to create subquerys from table a and b and then joining them like I tried to illustrate below:

```
select * from (Select * from (SELECT A,B,C FROM table1 where A =4756937 and B=290) as a
    join
      (SELECT D,E,F FROM table2) as b
      on a.A = b.E )as c
      join
      (SELECT G,H,I,J
      FROM table2) as d
      on c.F = d.H 
    order by A;
```

The reason is that

1. Like I already said I want to have only a subset of columns
2. I maybe want a special subset of data e.g. A =4756937

So **first question** would be: Is this an anti pattern? Or would a database system optimize the query anyway?

**Second question**: How would other programmers would like the style? Any good reason to do a SQL course?

**The last question**: In the last join after I already joined table a&b I joined the construct again on table d (which is also a subquery of table b) because I have duplicates in table b.

So the idea of my query is to get a specific nr from table a and joined it on  key column wihtin table b nothing special:
[image]

but table b also has another key column (b.f) which indicates that indicates a data row has something like a "little brother row". Thats why I joined table b (as a subquery again):

[image]

So again the question: Is what I did for this use cases reasonable and performance wise intelligent or did I somehow fall into a anti pattern?

Comment: is it Mysql or T-Sql ? You have tagged both both RDBMS

Comment: Skip the sub-queries. The dbms optimizer takes care of everything for you. Write readable code instead!

Comment: Please consider the next person that has to maintain your query. What a nightmare to read while a join is that much simpler and in most cases will perform better

Comment: Well, this *is* portable code, every DBMS supports it. For a simple query like your example using *Derived Tables* (that's the official name, a *Subquery* is in `WHERE`) is not needed. But for more complex queries you use them to apply aggregation or Distinct for a subset of the tables or simply split it into several logical groups to simplify testing or maintemance (e.g. submit only the DT Select to check the result). And then readability is better compared to a single monster Select :-)

Answer (score 6):

While I wouldn't really call it an antipattern, I do think it wiser to seperate the query parts:

- Result set
- Dataset
- Selector
- Sorting
- n/a in your case: Aggregation

So I would consider something like

```
SELECT -- Result set definition
  X.A AS A,
  X.B AS B,
  X.C AS C,
  Y.D AS D,
  Y.E AS E,
  Y.F AS F,
  Z.G AS G,
  Z.H AS H,
  Z.I AS I,
  Z.J AS J
FROM -- Dataset definition
  table1 AS X
  INNER JOIN table2 AS Y ON X.A=Y.E
  INNER JOIN table2 AS Z ON Y.F=Z.H
WHERE -- Selector
  X.A=4756937
  AND X.B=290
ORDER BY -- sorting
  X.A
;
```

Why would this be of advantage?

- it gives the biggest degree of freedom to the query optimizer
- it keeps all indices in all scopes (not all RDBMS can use out-of-scope indices, this is also true for MySQL, if the size of a nested subquery hits a ceiling)
- it is the most portable SQL: Maybe you want to use soemthing else than MySQL once?
- it is readable and maintainable: What if the structure of an underlying table or your result set requirements change?